# Call React class function from dangerouslySetInnerHtml content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For an application I am developing using ReactJS, I have to make an ajax call out to a service which is either going to return a JSON object (if successful) **or a small amount of HTML code (if not successful)**.  This HTML code has a link inside of it which needs to launch a modal control in my react app.  I cannot alter the HTML coming back from the ajax call because it is used in other applications.

The HTML will look something like this:

```
<span>ERROR MESSAGE HERE.</span>
<span>
    <a data-error-code="141096">
        <u>See details.</u>
    </a>
</span>
```

When the user clicks on that "See details" link, the modal should open, go get the detail message from the server and display it in the modal.  This works on other areas of the site already.

What I'm struggling with is handling the `onClick()` event attached to the `<a>` tag.  I have a method on my react component that the HTML will be rendered in named `showErrorModal` which will open the error detail modal.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**UPDATE: A jsFiddle with sample of what I need can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/830nqknn/1/).** In this case, I've hard-coded the HTML that I'm injecting into the div area.  What I need to do is to add an `onClick()` event to that anchor tag in the `htmlToInject` HTML string to call `handleClick()`.  I can't modify the contents of `htmlToInject` since that is generated server-side and I have no control over that.  This is pretty much the exact structure the server will be returning, and the reason I need that error messaging is because it is dynamic based on what the error is (ex: "There are no items in your bag that this coupon applies to" vs "This coupon is expired" vs "You don't qualify to use this coupon").  The separate messages are returned in individual `<span>` tags.  In the server call I do also get the error code returned so I don't need to worry about reading the `data-error-code` attribute.  what I get back from the server looks like:

```json
{
  success: false,
  error-code: 123456,
  error: "some HTML goes here"
}
```

When the call returns with data, I do a `this.setState()` to set those 3 values, so I already know what the error code is.

Comment: So the HTML you're showing is supposed to be rendered by your component's `render()` or in the dialog? Please illustrate your `render()` method for the component that needs to handle the click.

Comment: How is the onClick event added in other parts of the site?

Comment: @JMM the HTML returned from the server gets injected into a `div` on the component.  This HTML contains an anchor tag which I need to add an `onClick()` to which calls a method on the component to open the modal dialog.  I'll update the question in a moment with a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: @Joshua this is the only part of the site so far where I need to do this.  The other areas where I have to perform this `onClick()` task are just other areas where I need to open this modal, but those areas aren't rendered from dangerouslySetInnerHtml div areas.  If that makes sense...

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used some jQuery applied in just the right place ([updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/830nqknn/2/)):

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    $('.outsideHtml a').click(function(e){
        alert($(e.target).attr('data-error-code'))
    })
}
```

You'll probably want `componentDidUpdate` instead of or as  well as `componentDidMount`, if the component has an initial state before rendering the HTML (such as a 'Loading...' state). You may also need to do some `this` wrangling in the click handler function (or use ES2015) to call methods on the component instance.

I found that jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method didn't catch DOM inserted by React (at least via `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`). I'm guessing React's DOM manipulation bypasses something jQuery relies on. By the time the `componentDid...` functions are called the DOM is ready for jQuery.

Adding the click event handler could probably be achieved relatively easily in the DOM without jQuery but the concept would be the same.

Comment: I forgot about this question, but yeah that's pretty much what we wound up going with.  We only did it in update since the data is loaded after the component mounts (it required a user enter a code first, and then the code is checked against a list of known codes).  We are actually using the 'on' method as well, and that seems to work.  And we are doing some "this" wrangling by setting a variable to be a reference to 'this'.